# Fixed background image horizontally connected to content with fixed width

Tags: javascript, html, css, css-position

The problem is: I have a huge background image and content with those characteristics:

- the content is centered with `margin: auto;` and it has a fixed width
- the position of the content is in relation to the image (like it fits in the middle of the image)
- this connection is only horizontally (vertical scrolling moves everything around as expected)

This works fine, actually, on desktop devices with position fixed on the background image.

But the problem is: When I resize the window until it's smaller than the content, the content is fixed on the left side, but the background image is still centered, as expected. In this case the connection between both elements gets lost.

I have this JavaScript that does the trick, but this is of course some overhead I want to avoid as it isn't smooth anytime due to the calculation:

```js
$(window).resize(function(){
    container.css('left', (body.width() - img.width()) / 2);
});
```

I also tried things like that:

```html
<div id="test" style="
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 0;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%:
    height: 100%;
    background: transparent url(path) no-repeat fixed center top;
"></div>
```

But this results in the same issue described above.

Is there any elegant CSS solution for this problem?

**Demo**

[Try it yourself](http://jsfiddle.net/48EU9/)

**NOTE**

The image size is fixed and known and it never gets scaled by the browser.

Comment: I think an example fiddle to see the effect could be helpful

Comment: To answer your question, not really. You will notice the example the works has a much lower res for the background image than you. That is because in script they zoom the image to the appropiate height of the screen.

Comment: I guess you could force html to render the image the size of the screen but that would cause ratio problems in the image, better to zoom in.

Comment: It's only in the example with javascript, that the image gets resized (because of the CSS for the image). The "real world version" has always a fixed width. I cut it down a little for simplicity.

Comment: It has a fixed width because of the image size. You will notice this when you expand the view point as well, but I'll take a closer look and see if I can do something.

Comment: That's true. And this is how it should be, fixed and centered by it's width. Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Yea I see what you mean it looks like teh image isnt sticky but it is. It is sticking to the top of the page which is correct it is just the size of the image that is making it look like it aint (you can see this when you expand the window really big too). The problem to fixing this in CSS is that there is no way to rationally resize the image to the screen size in CSS while keeping pixel ratio consistent, that's why that working example uses JS. So I am not sure how this could be solved at all.

Comment: That's what I figured. Many thanks for your help.

Comment: Hmm I think I may have spoke too soon. For responsive design CSS3 might have a trick up its sleve: http://webdesignerwall.com/tutorials/responsive-design-with-css3-media-queries Check the "Flexible Images:" header there. You might be able to make a CSS3 media query adaptive resize the image.

Comment: Ah, sounds interesting I'll look into that.

Comment: Is this close to what you're looking for? http://jsfiddle.net/T2KP8/

Comment: The image link is 404'ing, so I can't see the problem.

Comment: @hitmanDX - thanks for your solution, but the problem still occurs and you loose the vertical scrolling over the image. I'll some screenshots tomorrow, to hopefully explain it better.

Comment: @Nightfirecat I've updated the fiddle. Somehow the lorempixel image got lost.

Comment: @insertusernamehere Strangely enough, I'm not seeing any problems when resizing the viewport horizontally. It seems to work at high and low widths just fine for me.

Comment: you can add varying different numbers in different units with the css calc. see here:https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/-moz-calc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this working for you? http://jsfiddle.net/wPmrm/24/

**HTML**

```
<div class="background">
<div class="content">
    CONTENT
    <br><br>
    This example works fine until you the viewport size gets smaller than this content. After that the image isn't sticky anymore.
    <br><br>
    And check out vertical scrolling.

    <div style="height:1500px;"></div>
    END
</div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
div.background {
    min-width: 740px;
    background: url('http://placehold.it/1600x1050') top center fixed no-repeat;
}

div.content {
    width: 700px;
    height: 2000px;
    margin: auto;
    padding: 50px 20px;
    background: none;
    opacity: 0.7;
    color: #333;
}
```

.background should be the wrapper for .content with a centered background and have a minimum-width of the .contents width+padding.

Update from comments:

http://jsfiddle.net/wPmrm/28/

We'll have to use a media-query, so when the width is at max 740px we change the background position. Oh and we set background-attachment to fixed again.

**CSS added**

```
@media screen and (max-width:740px) {
    div.background {
        background-position: -435px 0;
    }
}
```

I don't see why it is -435px ((1600-740)/2 would be 430) but it seems to be the most accurate value.

Comment: Hey, this works perfectly to center the image and it's sticky even if the window gets smaller than the content. But it doesn't have vertical scrolling "over" the background - means, when the user scrolls down only the content should move and not the background image. Argh, it's tricky. :)

Comment: Yeah it is, but I'll look what I can do ^^

Comment: Note with this solution that you'll have to change the negative bg-position if your image changes in width.

Comment: Yeah, as @Sammaye stated before, that it could work with media queries, it really does. That's pretty impressive. Many, many thanks. Now I can get rid of the JavaScript. Oh wait, there is IE8, but I managed it to get it working with this jQuery script: http://protofunc.com/scripts/jquery/mediaqueries/ Pretty nice and thanks again.